# Error CreateServer Binding for WMI Create website (C#)

Tags: c#, binding, wmi

Please help me!

I have reviewed about 100 source pages.

I just could not do it.

I work 2 days.

My last point is creating a Binding.

I'm getting an "Access Denied" error.

[TR]
Yaklaşık 100 kaynak sayfa inceledim.

Bir türlü yapamadım.

2 gündür uğraşıyorum.

Son geldiğim nokta Binding oluşturma.

"Access Denied" hatası alıyorum.

Error;

[image]

```
public void Creator()
{

    string hostName = "BuBirSitedir";
    string domainName = "www.bubirsitedir.com";

    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect;
    options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Default;

    ManagementClass classInstance = new ManagementClass("root\\WebAdministration", "Site", null);

    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftIISV2", "DESKTOP-MGA1F3C"), options);
    scope.Connect();

    ManagementBaseObject[] serverBindings = new ManagementBaseObject[3];
    serverBindings[0] = CreateServerBinding(scope, string.Format("{0}", hostName, domainName), "127.0.0.1", 40804);
    serverBindings[1] = CreateServerBinding(scope, string.Format("30603", hostName, domainName), "127.0.0.1", 30603);
    serverBindings[2] = CreateServerBinding(scope, string.Format("127.0.0.1", hostName, domainName), "127.0.0.1", 20402);
}

private static ManagementObject CreateServerBinding(ManagementScope scope, string hostName, string ip, int port)
{
    ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("ServerBinding"), null);
    ManagementObject mco = mc.CreateInstance();
    mco.Properties["Hostname"].Value = hostName;
    mco.Properties["IP"].Value = ip;
    mco.Properties["Port"].Value = port;
    mco.Put();
    return mco;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

My Computer (Right Click) > Manage > Computer Management (Local) > Services And Application > WMI Control (Right Click) > Security (tab) > List item select and click security button > Select User > All Allow > OK

Not list user. Click Advanced Button. Write "everyone" and enter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Fau.png)